# Ruby on Rails: Pass request params in controller to model's after_create event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
1) Procedure
     title
     document_number

2) Revision
     revision_number
```

In my procedure model, I defined a method after_create to automatically create a Revision with revision_number set to 0.1.

```
# app/models/procedure.rb

# How do I get revision_number from the request params in this method?
after_create do |procedure|
    procedure.revisions.create(revision_number: 0.1)
end
```

That works well, however, I do not want to always default to 0.1 - For example, if I want to specify a revision number from parameters sent in the form request to the controller, I am a bit lost there. I looked throughout the guides and I wasn't able to find a way to pass data into the create event. This is my method in my controller:

```
# app/controllers/procedures_controller.rb

def create
    @procedure = current_user.procedures.build(procedure_params)

    if @procedure.save
        render json: @procedure, status: :created, location: @procedure
    else
        render json: @procedure.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def procedure_params
    params.require(:procedure).permit(:title, :document_number, :revision_number)
end
```

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is by adding a column 'revision_number' to my procedure model, and then checking whether it is set in my 'after_create' method.

I would appreciate any other suggestions for how I might be able to tackle this problem. Or if there is already a way and I missed it in the guides, I would appreciate a reference to that section. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the relationships between your models

Comment: User has many Revisions and Procedures
Procedure has many Revisions, Procedure belongs to User and Revision belongs to User

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to violate  `MVC architecture` and `Single Responsiblity Principle`. `Controller` is responsible for `handling HTTP request` and `Model` is responsible for `interacting with database.`

In any case you commited to violate rules :-

```
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add_revision_number(number)
    self.revision_number = number
  end
end

class ProceduresController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    @procedure.add_revision_number(params[:revision_number])
    ...
  end
end
```

now access `revision_number` in model

I prefer not to pass controller `request` object directly. It Isolates model from current request.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I create a new Revision in the controller instead of my current approach?

Comment: Nope, I am just adding a attribute 'revision_number` in procedure object then you can access `revision_number` in `after_create`  block in model. Use debugger in `after_create` block and see if you are getting `revision_number` . Just like attribute setter method

Comment: You said I am violating the MVC architecture. So, do you suggest that I create a new Revision in the controller instead of my current approach?

Comment: May be .. It is not advisable to pass parameter from controller to model

Answer (score 1):

## app/models/procedure.rb

```
attr_accessor :revision_no

after_create do |procedure|
    procedure.revisions.create(revision_number: self.revision_no)
end
```

Now you can pass value in revision_no.